# Kivy: IO and database communication, possible?

Tags: android, python, ios, cross-platform, kivy

I want to make an application for IOS and android using Kivy. The application requires reading and writing to files and also communication with a database server. I am curious wether a kivy application with an implementation of file IO and database communication can be cross-platform? Meaning I can make e.g. an .apk for android of my python code and get it to work.

If not. Are there any solutions? Are there any APIs for solving the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically (!) Kivy supports all python packages, so you can use `sqlite` + `sqlalchemy` to store it your data directly on the device or maybe even remote database with SSL tunnel for transporting SQL. More [here](http://cheparev.com/kivy-sqlite/)

Comment: I have successfully used kivy with pymysql and sqlalchemy to implement file synchronization. The app communicates with a MySQL server without problems. But I have only tested it in Android